# Откуда тут столько циклов в плане запроса?

Tags: sql-server, анализ-плана-запроса

Допустим, есть такой запрос:

```
select * from Object1 Object2
where Object2.Column1 NOT IN (
SELECT Column2
  FROM Database1.Schema1.Object3)
```

И получаю вот такой план:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять, почему оптимизатор сделал столько циклов?

Да, предикаты немного отличаются. Однако, неужели не проще 1 раз все вычитать?

Кластерных индексов в таблицах нету.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Здесь видно проблему с операцией `NOT IN (SELECT ...)`

Оптимизатор сначала отсеивает все NULL значения из первой таблицы, потом проверяет наличие NULL значения во второй и уже третьим шагом ищет по конкретным ключам.

Если бы колонки Object2.Column1 и Object3.Column2 были объявлены как NOT NULL, то первых двух циклов (справа налево) не было бы.

Вообще стоит избегать конструкции `NOT IN (SELECT ...)`, так как строки с NULL значениями из первой таблицы никогда не будут возвращены, а одно NULL значение во второй таблице вообще приведет к тому, что запрос не вернет результата. Лучше переписать запрос через конструкцию 'NOT EXISTS':

```
SELECT *
FROM   Object1 Object2
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM   Database1.Schema1.Object3
    WHERE  Object2.Column1 = Column2
);
```

Для наглядности пример:

```
CREATE TABLE #test1
(
    Id      INT,
    Column1 VARCHAR(32) NULL
);

INSERT #test1
VALUES
(1, 'AAAA'),
(3, 'cccc'),
(5, NULL),
(6, 'eeee'),
(7, NULL),
(9, 'AAAA!')

select * from #test1 Object2
where Object2.Column1 NOT IN (
    SELECT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AAAA'
)
/*
Id          Column1
----------- --------------------------------

(0 rows affected)

*/
select * from #test1 Object2
where Object2.Column1 NOT IN (
SELECT 'AAAA'
)
/*
Id          Column1
----------- --------------------------------
2           bbbb
3           cccc
6           eeee
9           AAAA!

(4 rows affected)
*/
select * from #test1 Object2
where  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (
        SELECT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'AAAA'
    )x(Column2)
    WHERE Object2.Column1 = Column2
)

/*
Id          Column1
----------- --------------------------------
2           bbbb
3           cccc
5           NULL
6           eeee
7           NULL
9           AAAA!

(6 rows affected)
*/

DROP TABLE #test1;
```

Comment: `Вообще стоит избегать конструкции NOT IN (SELECT ...), так как строки с NULL значениями из первой таблицы никогда не будут возвращены, а одно NULL значение во второй таблице вообще приведет к тому, что запрос не вернет результата` под второй таблицей вы имеет ввиду так, которая в подзапросе NOT IN?

Comment: да, имелось ввиду, что первая таблица - это внешняя, а вторая - это в подзапросе

Comment: Я, вроде, проводил эксперименты с IN и NULL в подзапросе, но мне все успешно возвращалось.

Comment: Хм... А такая штука с NULL'ми только при использовании отрицания в IN. Если без него, то все нормально работает.